# MCrypt Inconsistent Between Servers When Decrypting

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have the below class with 2 Mcrypt methods. I am encrypting a string, sending it via JSONP through an API and having the consumer use the same decrypt method with the same salt and I am not able to decrypt the string. A test on the server can be successfully ran in terms of encrypting and decrypting on the same server, however when an encrypted string is encrypted on one server and attempted to be decrypted on another server using the correct salt it simply cannot decrypt it. With this mode (MCRYPT_MODE_ECB) it was my understanding an IV is not necessary. Does someone have any idea why this would be happening?

```
<?php

class McryptHelper
{
    /**
     * Encrypt
     * Encrypts a string using the MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 cipher and the MCRYPT_MODE_ECB.
     *
     * @static
     * @param string $string
     * @param string $salt
     * @return string
     */
    public static function encrypt($string, $salt)
    {
        $saltSize = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, $saltSize);
        $cipherText = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $encrypted = base64_encode($cipherText);

        return trim($encrypted);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt
     * Decrypts a string using the MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 cipher and the MCRYPT_MODE_ECB mode.
     *
     * @static
     * @param string $string
     * @param string $salt
     * @return string
     */
    public static function decrypt($string, $salt)
    {
        $saltSize = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, $saltSize);
        $cipherText = base64_decode($string);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $salt, $cipherText, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

        return trim($decrypted);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make sure that both ends really try to decrypt the *same* `$cipherText`? For example compare a hash of the data. And what is the error message exactly? Note that decrypt is not an exact inverse of encrypt, as any whitespace and null characters at the end of `$string` will be removed (you call `trim` on it, probably because mcrypt automatically zero pads the plain text (`$string`) before encryption).

Comment: Some cryptographic advice: You should (with very few exceptions) never ever use ECB. It has some serious problems, see the image on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29). Maybe use CFB or CBC? Furthermore encryption is not enough for most applications; you should also implement an authentication method. I would normally advice an AEAD block cipher mode for that job, but `mcrypt` does not seem to provide any. Instead you can use a encrypt-then-mac construction using HMAC.

Comment: @Perseids thanks that has helped me debug. Also I have switched to MCRYPT_MODE_CBC with an iv.

Comment: Also note that you have to use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` for AES. Have you looked at the sample code of `mcrypt_encrypt`? Note that a salt is not a key, make sure you name your variables right or confusion may arise... PS don't click through to the "advanced example"... that's still the old crap that I haven't had my hands on yet :)